# PowerApps BingMaps.GetMapV2 image trying to add multiple pushpins

Tags: bing-maps, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have added the below code to an image on my PowerApps canvas, if I add one pin it displays on the image/map but if I add 2 pins they don't display. I'm sure I've written it wrong or missed something... hopefully its not a limitation?

Any help would be great.

```json
BingMaps.GetMapV2(
    "Road",
    15,
    51.388474,
    0.193718,
    {
        pushpins: [
            {
                pushpinIconStyle: 46,
                pushpinLabel: "1",
                pushpinLatitude: 51.387918,
                pushpinLongitude: 0.191583
            },
            {
                pushpinIconStyle: 46,
                pushpinLabel: "2",
                pushpinLatitude: 51.387912,
                pushpinLongitude: 0.191582
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the `BingMaps.GetMapv2` in power apps. Digging into this it looks like you are loading a static map through the Bing Maps connector. It looks like this function only allows a single pushpin to be specified, thus your issue. Note that this connector is a thin and apparently, limited, wrapper around the [Bing Maps Imagery REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map). With that in mind, you would need to simple generate the REST API url for the image you want using this API directly. Here is a blog post on how to do this: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/image-control-static-maps-api/

If you decided to add more than a couple of pins, you may want to consider making the map interactive for a better user experience. The Power Apps team added built in maps capabilities using Azure Maps. Here are the docs on how to do that in power apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/geospatial-component-map